# Через canvas не отображается результат инвертации цвета

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Пытаюсь инвертировать цвета пиксельного изображения через canvas и отобразить на экране через ctx.putImageData(dataImg,0,0). Источник отображается, а инвертированный вариант нет. Приношу извинения за глупый вопрос заранее((

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
```

Вaш брaузeр нe поддeрживaeт canvas

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canv').getContext('2d');
var pic = new Image();
pic.src = 'img/penguins.png';
pic.onload = function() {
 ctx.drawImage(pic,0,0)
}
var dataImg = ctx.getImageData(0,0,pic.width,pic.height);
var pix = dataImg.data;
for (i=0; i<pix.length; i+=4)
{
 pix[i]=255- pix[i];
 pix[i+1]=255-pix[i+1];
 pix[i+2]=255-pix[i+2];
 pix[i+3]=255;
}
ctx.putImageData(dataImg,500,0);
```

```html
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<canvas id='canv' width='600' height='600'>Вaш брaузeр нe поддeрживaeт canvas</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код с преобразованием, необходимо поместить в обработчик события `load`.

```
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canv').getContext('2d');
    var pic = new Image();
    pic.src = 'img/penguins.png';
    pic.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(pic,0,0)

        var dataImg = ctx.getImageData(0,0,pic.width,pic.height);
        var pix = dataImg.data;
        for (i=0; i<pix.length; i+=4){
              pix[i]=255- pix[i];
              pix[i+1]=255-pix[i+1];
              pix[i+2]=255-pix[i+2];
              pix[i+3]=255;
        }
        ctx.putImageData(dataImg,500,0);
    }

    </script>
```